# use v-for to render children components

Tags: vue.js

can I use v-for to render children components in the parent element?

```
<todo-list>
 <todo-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :title="item.title" :index="index"></todo-item>
</todo-list>
```

Comment: Yes, and you'd better provide the `key` attribute in case the component cache do something tricky .

Comment: @Hao please upvote and accept answers. People will be more eager to help you if you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

[It's clearly explained in the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component).